# How can I disable Javascript syntax checking in NetBeans 7.0 (Linux version for PHP)?

Tags: php, javascript, linux, netbeans, syntax

Maybe I'm blind, but I can't find this option and Google doesn't want to help me.

Sometimes NetBeans tries to check syntax in any file when detects some JS, but many templating frameworks/libraries put JS with PHP or special tags, causing that NetBeans throws syntax error in the file.

Comment: Hello, I know this question is somewhat old and maybe you're no longer looking for a reply to this. Have you tried out the "Ignored folders" tab inside of your project properties?

Comment: @César you are right, even I'm not using NetBeans anymore. The problem with your solution is that I wanted to work on those files, and "Ignored Folders" will hide the files from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I am using **netbeans 8.1** and I can easily manage this type of options by these steps. I think it is also available for **netbeans 7** .

1. Click **Tools** option in header menu and select **Options** from this menu.

   [image]
2. Select **Editor** from this popup.

   [image: Select Editor from Pop]
3. Now you will see submenu below . Select **Hint**

   [image: Hint]
4. Select language for you Javascript and then uncheck  all options that you don't need and save.

This way to you can enable or disable syntax checking option for all languages. and you can also manage formatting, code folding, spelling checker etc

Answer (score -5):

As far as I know you cannot really disable error checking (if that is what you're asking), if your code is broken.. fix it.

However you can disable so called "hints" for Javascript.

You can find this option in the tools menu (found under "options"). 
In the top menubar choose "editor" and go to the "hint" tab.

In the language dropdown select Javascript. You will see a list of warnings which you can disable.

You can however disable syntax highlighting, this is found in the same menu but under the option "fonts & colors" and the tab "highlighting". However you cannot choose for which language you want to do this.

Comment: I don't think this is what @mchurichi is asking about. In Netbeans, the IDE wants to be too smart and check JS syntax in JSP and JSPF files. As we all know that with various includes, script tags, dynamic script loading, JS code in a file could easily appear broken when in fact it isn't. This is one of those really annoying things in Netbeans that can't be turned off, or at least I haven't found a way to turn it off. Telling him to "fix the code" is unhelpful, accusatory and ignorant.

Comment: Thanks @bluecollarcoder, that's exactly what I want, I updated the description to avoid misunderstandings