# Netbeans 8.0.2's Syntax Highlight and Code Folding not working for PHP, HTML, Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, netbeans

I am using ubuntu 15.10 and used ubuntu software center for netbean's installation. So, here is the list of not working functionality which I noticed.

- In html files, it show red color when select tags, no code folding, enter button is not working for lines and no code completion.
- In Javascript files, it show plain-text only.
- In Php files, only code folding is not working.

I know how to disable or enable syntax. I have also answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835249/how-can-i-disable-javascript-syntax-checking-in-netbeans-7-0-linux-version-for).

**I think it is because a plugin is not installed. If so, I really don't know which plugins I should install for php developement**.

**EDIT**

*One more thing I want to show you my installed plugins are shown in the below image*

[image]

**Please help me with Answers/Suggestions. Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: Try lastest version (8.2) for PHP based on your architecture : http://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: why 8.0.2 not working

Comment: I noticed while doing my java class work this past term that the apt installed Netbeans lacks some functionality compared to the download-and-run-the-sh-file netbeans you'll get from the netbeans.org site.  Also noticed that that version of netbeans had some issues with openjdk - add the webupd8 full oracle java and it shoudl all work nicely together - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Netbeans` was primarily developed as `Java` programming IDE. So all functionality for programming languages other than `Java` is not hardcoded into `Netbeans` internal functionality but can be ensured by external plugins.

It seems that `Ubuntu` software center contains general `Netbeans` bundle that can work with `Java` but lacks `PHP` plugins (and perhaps highlights some `PHP` syntax because of its similarity to `Java` syntax).

You can find out what plugins you need and install them, but more convenient solution is to download and install from [official site](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) `PHP Netbeans bundle` which includes all functionality for `PHP` Web-development including `PHP`, `HTML` and `JavaScript` syntax highlightning and code folding.